# How can I better see "Find" results more clearly in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, accessibility

I used to use the Findbar Tweak add-on for Firefox before FireFox 57 broke it. I've searched around and there are solutions for highlight all results, search in all tabs, etc. But I haven't found a way to reproduce the feature I really need: the big ol' fuchsia circle that would appear and contract to show me where exactly it had found the result.

[image]

This is mostly a visual accessibility thing, because I have trouble spotting one highlighted word on a page full of words, but it's also useful when the result isn't actually visible on the page (because it's in a header, menu, dropdown, collapsed paragraph, etc.) - I can see "oh, the result is in that dropdown" or "oh, the result is on the bottom of the page below any text I can see, must be somewhere in the source that's not displayed".

How can I get FireFox to better visually indicate where in the page the highlighted result(s) are? Bonus points if it also [shows results on the scrollbar like in Eclipse, or if the Find bar closes when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> again, instead of having to use the mouse to find the little X:

[image]

These are the other 2 features I appreciated. But the visual "bwong, it's right here" is the important part.

Comment: It is now available in latest FF - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/87.0/releasenotes/

Comment: @kanlukasz Just the part where it shows results in the scroll bar (if you have Highlight All turned on), yeah? There's still no native way to get the zeroing-in circle that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I have been able to find thus far is the [Find in Page with Preview](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/find-in-page-with-preview/) add-on, which shows a zoomed preview of the result that you can click on, and it will scroll you to that location.

You can assign a short-cut key like CTRL+SHIFT+F to it as it works separately from the 'find in page' function within Firefox. The preview can be shown as sidebar or pop-up. Check under manage extension for those settings.

Answer (score 2):

My own solution to the problem of Firefox abandoning what is called
Legacy or XUL addons, was to pass to a Firefox fork that kept the support
of these addons.

For me there was no way that I could give up my Firefox environment
with the dozens of extensions that I use daily
and that were not ported to the new WebExtensions API.

Some such browser forks are
[Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/)
or
[Basilisk](https://www.basilisk-browser.org/)
or
[Waterfox](https://www.waterfox.net/),
which still support my old extensions, and which are still actively
supported and improved.

Extensions for the old format whose `.xpi` files you have not saved,
may be found in the Github web page of
[Classic Add-ons Archive](https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/releases),
which is itself an `.xpi` Legacy addon, or in the website of the browser
that you have chosen.